# Awk condition along with header

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

I have a dummy `employee.txt` file as follows to play around with `awk`:

```
100  Thomas  Manager    Sales       $5,000
200  Jason   Developer  Technology  $5,500
300  Sanjay  Sysadmin   Technology  $7,000
400  Nisha   Manager    Marketing   $9,500
500  Randy   DBA        Technology  $6,000
```

When attempting to print all employees with `$1` > `200`, am able to do so using the following

```
cat employees.txt | awk '$1 > 200'
```

However, I am now trying to add a custom heading along with the above condition as shown:

```
cat employees.txt | awk '
BEGIN{print "ID|Name|Designation|Department|Salary";OFS="|"}
{print $1 > 200}
END{print"------------------------"}'
```

The above code does not seem to work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `awk`, the "body" must have a syntax as follows:

```
condition{command}
```

When `condition` is met `command` is done with the current line. It can also be:

```
{command}
```

... without a `condition`, so it will e executed for *every* line. This is also valid:

```
condition
```

... without a `command`, then `awk` just prints `$0`, hence the whole line, when `condition` is met.

---

Your `awk` should look:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "ID|Name|Designation|Department|Salary";OFS="|"} 
  $1>200{$1=$1;print} END{print"------------------------"}' file
```

Notice `$1=$1`. This is needed because you only change the ouput field separator. Therefore you'll need to either print the fields one by one (`$1,$2,...`) or force the reconstruction of the record by `$n=$n`.

Comment: Nice! Why doesn't it work by saying `$0=$0` instead of `$1=$1`?

Comment: @fedorqui Because `$0` contains the line untouched, with the original delimiters. It would just set `$0` to `$0`. `$1=$1` forces awk to rebuild the array of fields. When you change a field, awk rebuilds the `$0` variable, with new delimiters.

Comment: `$1>200{$1=$1;print}` can be changed to `{$1=$1}$1>200`

Comment: @Costas No, the line is not printed then. Only the array is rebuilt.

Comment: Are you jocking? From your answer `condition without a command, then awk just prints $0` : `{$1=$1}` rebuilds $0 then `$1>200` == *condition wthout command*.

Comment: @Costas I'm not joking =). I tried it with this:  `$1>200{$1=$1}`. But, why is `{$1=$1}$1>200` printing the lines and `$1>200{$1=$1}` not?, It's just condition and command swapped?

Comment: See your answer above. *condition wthout command* is the same as `condition{print}` so `{$1=$1}$1>200` is short form of `{$1=$1}$1>200{print}` but `$1>200{$1=$1}` is just `$1>200{$1=$1}` because *condition* `$1>200` has command `{$1=$1}`

Comment: @Costas Thanks for pointing that out. There's always a shorter way.

Answer (score 2):

use either

```
 BEGIN { ... }
 $1 > 200
 END { .. }
```

or

```
 BEGIN { ... }
 $1 > 200 { print ;}
 END { .. }
```

the instruction you use  print all first field ($1) to "filename" 200.